# DB2 docker on Mackbook Air M1

Tags: docker, db2

I am following the [official instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.db2u_openshift.doc/doc/t_install_db2CE_mac_img.html) to run DB2 in docker. I have done this successfully countless times on macOS Intel. I have also done this successfully in Windows 10. But now I am trying to do this in macOS Apple chip (Macbook Air M1). I do this by adding the `--platform linux/amd64` option to `docker pull` and `docker run`.

This creates the container OK. But all sorts of things go wrong with DB2. First of it appears that DB2 does not start. I manually run `db2start` to take care of that. Then I have trouble creating a database and connecting to it. I get this message:

```
SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system
```

Looking at `db2diag.log` does not show any specific error messages.

What do I need to do to run DB2 in docker in Apple silicone?

Comment: Just a note: I don't like running DB2 as a docker container directly on the OS. It requires you to add `--privileged=true` and this can open a BIG security hole in your whole computer. Maybe you should consider running docker inside a VM just to be on the safe side. Well... if you run docker in a VM, then you can pick any free linux flavor, and you won't need to deal with mac features.

Comment: The Impaler, I had tried that option also. macOS ARM -> Intel linux VM -> DB2 docker container. DB2 was having strange problems there as well. For now we are going with a remote DB2 install in a Windows box. But it will be nice to have it running in my Macbook.

Comment: There's more detail about this problem in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175677/ibmcom-db2-docker-image-fails-on-m1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ibmcom/db2 docker image fails on m1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175677/ibmcom-db2-docker-image-fails-on-m1)